# convert a jpg file after being uploaded using inotifywait

Tags: bash, inotify

First it is my first time writing a bash script so I apologize if this is trivial. I am trying to setup a watch so every time a `jpg` file is uploaded to a specific folder, it gets converted to `webp` using `cwebp`. after googling the web, it seemed that using inotifywait is the best way (please let me know if that is not correct). reading bash script manual and [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) page I managed to write this code:

```
inotifywait -m /home/ben -e create -e moved_to |
    while read path action file; do
        # echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'"
        if [[ $file = *.jpg ]]
        then
             cwebp $file -o $file.webp
        fi
    done
```

this works when I use for example `mv` command but when using the code above, I get this error:

```
Could not read 0 bytes of data from file test.jpg
Error! Could not process file test.jpg
Error! Cannot read input picture file 'test.jpg'
```

if I run the command `cwebp test.jpg -o test.jpg.webp` separately, it executes without any errors.
what am I doing wrong? this triggers after the file is created, why `cwebp` is getting 0 bytes?

Comment: Maybe the file had been opened (created) but not yet written to? Try close_write instead?

Comment: Side note: You should quote your variables and check the script with [shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck).

Comment: Jeff, Thank you. close_write was the right event to use.
Marco, thank you for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inotifywait script you had was using `-e create` instead of `-e close_write`; the difference is that the create event will fire off before data has been written to the file; thus, `cwebp` had "0 bytes of data from file".

From the [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) page you referenced:

> - create
>
> A file or directory was created within a watched directory.
>
> - close_write
>
> A watched file or a file within a watched directory was closed, after
>   being opened in writeable mode. This does not necessarily imply the
>   file was written to.